# Only header and footer showing when react app is opened

Tags: reactjs, routes

https://williamgrube1.github.io/Library/
[App.jsx code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr0cN.png)

When react app is opened only the header and footer show until you click on a link. How is this fixed?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: this behaviour is expected because you don't have a `/library` route in your routers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.